# Making a Typescript wrapper of Array.flat(1) with generics

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that makes an array from the arguments, accepting only one type or one deep arrays of that same type. Pretty much `(...items)=>items.flat(1)`, yet type safe and with generics. I'm fairly sure that a necessary restriction is that the type collected must not be an array itself, since `.flat()` would spill the contents into the return value, polluting it.

The goal function, yet with a generic `T` instead of `number`:

```ts
function arrayOfNumber(...items: (number | number[])[]): number[] {
    return items.flat(1);
}
```

When directly replacing `number` with a generic, it fails:

```ts
function arrayOfGenericFailure<T>(...items: (T | T[])[]): T[] {
    return items.flat(1);
}
// Throws:
// Type '(T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T))[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
//   Type 'T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T)' is not assignable to type 'T'.
//     'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T)'.(2322)
```

I'm assuming the `infer InnerArr` bits are there to address the previously mentioned array as the type issue; please correct me if that's wrong.

A nearly-there solution:

```ts
type NotArray<T> = Exclude<T, Array<any>>;
export function arrayOfX<T>(...items: (NotArray<T> | NotArray<T>[])[]): T[] {
    return items.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [] as T[]);
}
```

This passes type checks, yet seems messy and is also restricting the argument types rather than the generic itself. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see you're using `.flat(1)` (that's the default, by the way). So you don't need to handle (say) `T[][]`?

Comment: Nevermind, your parameter signature in `arrayOfX` answers that question if I look at it properly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you:

#### A simple loop

Since your array element type is explicitly just `T` or `T[]`, and `flat`'s types are markedly complicated by the fact it has to handle going deeper than that, and you seem happy to use something other than `flat`, I'd opt for a simple `for..of` loop:

```typescript
function arrayOfX<ElementType>(a: (ElementType | ElementType[])[]): ElementType[] {
    const result: ElementType[] = [];
    for (const element of a) {
        if (Array.isArray(element)) {
            result.push(...element);
        } else {
            result.push(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

That avoids any type assertions or type gymnastics and is quite simple to read and maintain.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwPLABoA8AogDYCmAtmWFACqYAOZAfABTIBcirpl1djMogA+iXlRr0mAbQC6ASjnyu4-lLJzEAbwBQifYggIAzlESoyxkCSgryEgTNmIAvIjkBuPQeBxU3IzBTRDJ7fkQ4YBR5bW8DAxgo1gBBdCwAOhhjVIxMVlC+GnkY3XiygwsrG3SGEGMAC1Z05oKHeS9y-QBfEJJjIVLO+MrrKBq6xtb+driyrtn54bIoEFQkEZsvecDgjagARlcUNJx8Vml9gBpEACZr6QBma4AWZwUPIYB6T8QwEAoAEZkVByHQ7Mx7G5HNC5XB4c5XW73ABEUHqFjIyJeb3a+m+3FMqBgYAA5iJfv8gahFLIdEA)

#### A "soft" type assertion

Another answer — but I suspect you considered and rejected this — is to just throw a single type assertion at the `flat` version; the types are similar enough that it can be directly asserted (no `as unknown` clause needed):

```typescript
function arrayOfX<ElementType>(a: (ElementType | ElementType[])[]): ElementType[] {
    return a.flat() as ElementType[];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwPLABoA8AogDYCmAtmWFACqYAOZAfABTIBcirpl1djMogA+iXlRr0mAbQC6ASjnyu4-lLJzEAbwBQifYlRkoIVEmQA6YCWRRW8lAGcx5CQJmyA3DoC+OiAiOUIZkjiAkUACMiAC8KOhYuHis0pEANIgATBnSAMwZACyyiAqeBuWIAPSViGAgFABGZKhy-oHBRmERmbHxGDj4KelZOQBEUAAWRmSjhcWl+tXcQagwYADmIrX1TaiKsjpAA)

I avoid type assertions as rigorously as I can **except** in *small* utility functions like this one where there's no possibility of the assertion being incorrect, it's just that I'm using something like `flat` that has seriously complex typing to handle cases my utility function won't be throwing at it.

Comment: That said, I won't be surprised if someone like [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) or [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) can come up with some type gymnastics to make the `flat` version work without a type assertion.